# How to apply Geomertic mean in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch-geometric

- I am trying to built a function to calculate the Geometric mean for `Growth` column and `Avg_growth`.

| Year | Company Name | FH_PBIDT | Growth | Avg_growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009-10 | Aayush Food & Herbs Ltd. | 0.044881 | 0.000000 | -0.773403 |
| 2010-11 | Aayush Food & Herbs Ltd. | 0.063545 | 0.415839 | -0.773403 |

- For that, I am using the below code:

`from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean`

- I created a column name:

`df['Geometric Mean'] = gmean(df.iloc[:,3])`

`df['Avg_Growth Mean'] = gmean(df.iloc[:,4])`

- I am getting an error that gmean is not defined. Could someone help me here?

Comment: What is your exact error?

Comment: Error i am getting

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'gmean'

Answer (score 1):

Can also write a geometric mean function by a little help  from Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

def geometric_mean(i):
    x = np.array(i)
    return x.prod()**(1.0/len(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as your error `'Series' object has no attribute 'gmean'`, make sure you are not doing this anywhere in your code:

```py
# wrong way of calling gmean on a series
df.iloc[:,4].gmean() # accessing gmean as a function on series object
```

Instead how you have called gmean in your question description above is correct and works:

```py
df['Avg_Growth Mean'] = gmean(df.iloc[:,4]) #works!
```

However, there might be more than one thing wrong here,

I tried testing code on data given by you and while `gmean` is available from the `scipy.stats.mstats` module, and it can be executed; the data is not apt for calculation of a geometric mean.

There is a zero value in `Growth` column, and negative values given in `Avg Growth` column. You can not find Geometric mean in case of negatives and zeroes: [see this link for more details](https://buzzardsbay.org/special-topics/calculating-geometric-mean/#:%7E:text=Like%20zero%2C%20it%20is%20impossible,Geometric%20Mean%20with%20negative%20numbers.&text=For%20example%2C%20to%20calculate%20the,a%20geometric%20mean%20of%201.0167.)

See the image below for code I executed:
[image: Jupyternotebook screenshot with code]